# File size for PNG?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I have a friend that wants me to do a design for T-Shirts.
They have a fancy machine that does the printing for them on the cloth.
It wants the design to be in PNG file size so they can make it on small or large as needed to fit the different sizes of shirts.
I need some help on the best way & what size I should start out working on? I am working with Photoshop 3.

Comment: Welcome to the site but a few things here:  1) PNG is not the best format for printing you should look at using or building a vector to be able to obtain a crisp edge.  2) I'd suggest using the search feature we have several questions around printing, t-shirts, PNG and file setup.  I closed your question as too broad because there are too many variables in play such as type, dimensions, printer spec.

Comment: @DᴀʀᴛʜVᴀᴅᴇʀ There seem to be a couple of questions here lately regarding the use of PNG images in printing. Many seem to think that transparency is required for printing. Not sure where this misinformation is coming from - perhaps it's the mistake belief that white backgrounds will be printed with white ink.

Answer (score 1):

You can set up a new raster document in Photoshop with any dimensions you want to set. There is no standard size. Also this has nothing to do with the *file size* of the PNG image. Also, PNGs are not designed for printing (*see note below).  There are a couple of things you need to find out before you start:

1. Ask your T-shirt printing company what resolution the image needs to be.
2. Work out the size the image will be printed in inches.  Measure it on an actual T-shirt if you have to. Choose the biggest T-shirt size that it will be printed on.
3. Then take that resolution, and multiply by each dimension in inches. That will give you the number of pixels for each dimension.

For example: say your image will be printed at 10" x 20". And let's say the resolution is 150 dpi.

10" x 150dpi = 1500px

20" x 150dpi = 3000px

So, the image in Photoshop should be 1500px x 3000px, at 150ppi.  You can set all these things in Photoshop when you create a new file.  Or you can even let Photoshop work it out for you, insert the dimension in inches, put in the PPI, and Photoshop will automatically work out the number of pixels required.

*Note: PNG images are not usually used for printing, since the format doesn't support CMYK. PNG images are a web image format. Please double check this with your printer! I suppose if all they need is an RGB file and the T-shirts are being printed digitally, then it might be OK.  The usual industry standard raster format for full colour printing is CMYK TIF.

Comment: The 'PNG can be any size you want' might be a bit misleading for people new in the industry. While you can scale any image to any size you want, a PNG will get pixelized or blurry when scaling while a vector based image wouldn't.

Comment: I was talking about the image size, not rescaling. I'll attempt an edit to make that clearer.

Comment: Ah sorry, OP said 'so they can make it on small or large as needed to fit the different sizes of shirts.' so I figured he was talking about scaling an image up or down.

Comment: No need to apologise, I admit my answer wasn't clear enough. I've edited it. Thanks for noticing that!